# Oracle SQL Update

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have two tables XX_1 and XX_MAP_1. The structure is as follows.

XX_1

```
XX_EMPLOYEE_ID    XX_GTN_NBR   ERNCD
00001              21
00001              23
00120              34
00120              37
00120              23
```

XX_MAP_1

```
XX_GTN        ERNCD
 21            A1
 22            A2
 23            BB1
 34            AB1
```

......

I need to be able to update XX_1 table (field ERNCD) with matching values from XX_MAP_1 where XX_GTN_NBR matches

Expected result

```
XX_EMPLOYEE_ID    XX_GTN_NBR   ERNCD
00001              21           A1
00001              23           BB1
00120              34           AB1  
00120              37
00120              23           BB1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases `merge` is the preferred solution. It has been provided already.

Below is a solution using the join update syntax (which, according to another posted answer, "Oracle doesn't support"). Presented here not to compete with the `merge` solution, but just to show that Oracle does support a join update syntax.

Here is the `update` statement:

```
update ( select x.erncd as x_erncd, m.erncd as m_erncd 
         from   xx_1 x inner join xx_map_1 m on x.xx_gtn_nbr = m.xx_gtn
       )
set x_erncd = m_erncd;
```

And here is a compete session to show how this works.

```
create table xx_map_1 (xx_gtn number primary key, erncd varchar2(10));

insert into xx_map_1
  select 21, 'A1'  from dual union all
  select 22, 'A2'  from dual union all
  select 23, 'BB1' from dual union all
  select 34, 'AB1' from dual
;
select * from xx_map_1;

    XX_GTN ERNCD    
---------- ----------
        21 A1        
        22 A2        
        23 BB1       
        34 AB1 

create table xx_1 (xx_employee_id varchar2(20), xx_gtn_nbr number, erncd varchar2(10));

insert into xx_1
  select '00001', 21, null from dual union all
  select '00001', 23, null from dual union all
  select '00120', 34, null from dual union all
  select '00120', 37, null from dual union all
  select '00120', 23, null from dual
;
select * from xx_1;

XX_EMPLOYEE_ID       XX_GTN_NBR ERNCD    
-------------------- ---------- ----------
00001                        21           
00001                        23           
00120                        34           
00120                        37           
00120                        23
```

`insert` statement and result:

```
update ( select x.erncd as x_erncd, m.erncd as m_erncd 
         from   xx_1 x inner join xx_map_1 m on x.xx_gtn_nbr = m.xx_gtn
       )
set x_erncd = m_erncd;

select * from xx_1;

XX_EMPLOYEE_ID       XX_GTN_NBR ERNCD    
-------------------- ---------- ----------
00001                        21 A1        
00001                        23 BB1       
00120                        34 AB1       
00120                        37           
00120                        23 BB1
```

Comment: Thank you , merge was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't support a join update syntax, but you can use an `UPDATE` with a subquery instead:

```
UPDATE XX_1 t1
SET ERNCD = (SELECT t2.ERNCD FROM XX_MAP_1 t2 WHERE t2.XX_GTN = t1.XX_GTN_NBR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the merge statement using the clause "WHEN MATCHED THEN" only.

```
MERGE INTO XX_1 X
USING XX_MAP_1 XM
ON (X.XX_GTN_NBR = XM.XX_GTN)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET X.ERNCD = XM.ERNCD;
```